# FastAPI & GINO can't get all rows from table in db

Tags: python, orm, fastapi, starlette, gino

I am stuck into a problem with GINO. I can get a one row from my table called templates, so in the other route i want to get all rows from table. Here you can see my view for get one record from db ant it works perfect.

```
@router.get("/templates/{uid}")
async def get_template(uid: str):
    temp = await Template.get_or_404(uid)
    return temp.to_dict()
```

Next you can look at my view to add record to db and it also works fine:

```
@router.post("/templates")
async def add_template(template: TemplateModel):
    rv = await Template.create(name=template.name, text=template.text)
    return rv.to_dict()
```

So, the main cause in this view, it doesn't work:

```
@router.get("/templates/all")
async def get_all_templates():
    temp = await Template.all()
    return temp.to_dict()
```

Look down below for my Template model:

```
class Template(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "templates"

    UUID = db.Column(
        str(UUID(as_uuid=True)),
        db.String,
        primary_key=True,
        default=str(uuid.uuid4()),
        unique=True,
        nullable=False,
    )
    name = db.Column("name", db.String, nullable=False)
    text = db.Column("text", db.String, nullable=False)
    created_at = db.Column("created_at", db.DateTime, nullable=False,
                           server_default=db.func.now())
```

And finally my db GINO engine:

```
from gino_starlette import Gino
from .. import config

db = Gino(
    dsn=config.DB_DSN,
    pool_min_size=config.DB_POOL_MIN_SIZE,
    pool_max_size=config.DB_POOL_MAX_SIZE,
    echo=config.DB_ECHO,
)
```

ERROR LOG:

```
2020-08-08 12:07:57,698 INFO gino.engine._SAEngine SELECT templates."UUID", templates.name, templates.text, templates.created_at

FROM templates

WHERE templates."UUID" = $1

2020-08-08 12:07:57,699 INFO gino.engine._SAEngine ('all',)

INFO: 172.23.0.1:40676 - "GET /templates/all HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found
```

Please tell me what's wrong, i spent so much time to solve this problem. Feel free to answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

However i don't know about it. And GINO documentation doesn't tell that the operations with db using GINO models like get all records from db should requesting in POST. So the correct answer is replace router.get to router.post:

```
@router.post("/templates/all")
async def get_all_templates():
    temp = await Template.all()
    return temp.to_dict()
```